# LESS css class hierarchy

Tags: css, less

I have a list of chat contacts, where every contact can have a different state expressed by classes:

- .online
- .offline
- .online .selected
- .offline .selected

These are the related styles (example):

```
.online {
   background-color: #fff;
   p { color: #000; }
}

.selected {
   background-color: #000;
   p { color: #fff; }  // This doesn't take effect
}
```

Stylewise I always want the styles applied to .selected be dominant, but unfortunately it only changes the background-color (from the top level), when I add the .selected class.

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't support LESS css unfortunately :/

Comment: If you can't do a fiddle, do you at least have a site page we can look at?  This should be a simple solution but I think we are missing some key information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that when it gets compiled something happens that ends up changing the order (although it shouldn't). First things first, as well as showing us your LESS can you show us your compiled CSS ([Procssor](http://procssor.com/) is great for prettying up after compiling), this should give us a better idea of what the browser sees, can you also show us the HTML for your elements.

Having said all that the simple solution, especially as you want the selected to always be dominant is to use `!important`

```
.online {
   background-color: #fff;
   p { color: #000; }
}

.selected {
   background-color: #000!important;
   p { color: #fff!important; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are changing the `<p>` element with the CSS you need to make the CSS look like this:

```
.selected p {
    background-color: #0000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The same goes for the .online class

if you need 2 different states, then add the extra CSS:

```
.selected {
    // basic code
}

.selected p {
    // extended code to p element
}
```

Comment: I am using LESS css as a preprocessor. Even if I change it to .selected p nothing happens. :/ Does LESS influence the order of the declarations?